# Implementing Swipe refresh for RecyclerView in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, swiperefreshlayout

I want to refresh the `RecyclerView` each time I swipe down. So I use `SwipeRefreshLayout` but now also I am not able to refresh my `RecyclerView`.
Below is the code that I had written:

Below is my XML file named:fragment_static.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Below is my java file named:StaticFragment.java

```
public class StaticFragment extends Fragment  {
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    RecyclerView recyclerView ;
    private List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private FileAdapter mAdapter ;

    public StaticFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_static, container, false);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.container);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new    SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Refresh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                         Fragment frg = null;
                         frg = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Marker");
                         FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ft.detach(frg);
                        ft.attach(frg);
                        ft.commit();
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
         });


         recyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
         mAdapter = new FileAdapter(fileList);
         RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext().getApplicationContext());

         recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
         recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
         recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

         recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getContext(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                 Intent i = new Intent(getContext(),GraphActivityStatic.class);
                 i.putExtra("file_name",fileList.get(position));
                 startActivity(i);
             }

             @Override
             public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

             }
       }));

    prepareFileData();
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

private void prepareFileData() {
    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/PulseData/");
    if(!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdir();
    int position = 0;
    fileList.clear();
    for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (f.isFile() && f.toString().contains(".txt")) {
            fileList.add(f.getName());
            mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position++);
        }
    }

}



public interface ClickListener {
    void onClick(View view, int position);

    void onLongClick(View view, int position);
}

public static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private StaticFragment.ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final StaticFragment.ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}
}
```

It is giving me error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     java.lang.NullPointerException
     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:726)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You just want to show Toast message when swipe?

Comment: @Adley No I want to show it once it is refreshed

Answer (score 3):

The SwipeRefresh don't refresh/reload automatic. You need to add some logic into your function. You don't need and isn't a good pratice use delay (it's only for examples and tests).

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new    SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                // Do some logic
                // if (refresh is ok)
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Refresh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
         });
```

for example you can put all code that you want to reload inside a bind and call the bind inside SwipeListner:

```
function void bindMyReclyclerView(){
// bind here your recyclerView
}

mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new    SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    bindMyRecyclerView();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Refresh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
             });
```

I've done some similar in my app, take look at [This class on GitHub](https://github.com/adleywd/WhatsNextSeries/blob/master/app/src/main/java/br/com/adley/myseriesproject/activities/HomeActivity.java).

You can reload all activity too, but I don't recommend this! (But you can use for tests)

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new    SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        finish();
                        startActivity(getIntent());
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Refresh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                 });
```

Comment: can you tell what should i do to refresh the my recycler view as I used     Fragment frg = null;
      frg = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Marker");
     FragmentTransaction ft =getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     ft.detach(frg);
     ft.attach(frg);
     ft.commit(); but it is not refreshing my recyclerview.

Comment: First don't use new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {} cause it can freeze main thread. You don't necessarily need to reconstruct your fragment. You just need to re-bind your recyclerview.(Clear data and bind again, you can use the same code that you used to first bind). it's hard to say how you can do this because it's about logic and for this i'll need to understand all your code and what you want to do.